# How Can I Define Additional Blending Modes in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, blending

I would like to define additional blending modes in Three.js, like the ones you can find in Photoshop. For example:

Linear burn: 
pixel = (src + dst) - 1.0

Screen:
pixel = (src + dst) - (src * dst)

The full list of blending modes I want to add, along with their equations, can be found at this link: 
http://www.nutty.ca/articles/blend_modes/

ThreeJs only has Normal, Additive, Subtractive, and Multiply blending available without using Custom Blending Modes. However, Lightest and Darkest are easily added by using "CustomBlending" and Three's blending equations. For example:

```
material.blending = THREE[ "CustomBlending" ];
if(blendMode === "Lightest"){
    material.blendEquation = THREE.MaxEquation;
}
if(blendMode === "Darkest"){
    material.blendEquation = THREE.MinEquation;
}
```

Read more about Custom Blending Equations here:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/CustomBlendingEquations

My question is: **How can I define addtitional blendEquations?**

I've been looking at the src files for Three on Github, specifically WebGLState.js where the blendEquations seem to be defined. Below is where the AddEquation seems to be defined:

```
if ( currentBlendEquation !== AddEquation || currentBlendEquationAlpha !== AddEquation ) {

    gl.blendEquation( gl.FUNC_ADD );

    currentBlendEquation = AddEquation;
    currentBlendEquationAlpha = AddEquation;

}
```

You can view the code here: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/118ef7cd4426c5bd5a01bc5102eb1d97d89578ed/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLState.js

I cant seem to find where the other blendFunctions are defined, though. Can anyone please help me with this? Is the best way to do this editing the Three.js src files? Are defining source and destination factors (material.blendSrc = THREE.SrcAlphaFactor;) a part of this?

Thanks!